# When system language changes, font isn't applied

Tags: java, android, fonts

I want my app to support different languages, now I've added only two (English and Russian), because faced this problem. I've also added a font to the whole app in styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       ...
       ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/finger_paint</item> // this line
</style>
```

As my phone language is English usually, with English my app works well, the font is applied:
[image]

But when I change my phone language to Russian, something strange happens:
[image]

The font is applied for numbers but not Russian words!
I tried to make another drawable resource file (styles-ru.xml) and add font there, but nothing changed:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/carter_one</item> // this line
</style>
```

My values folder looks like:
[image]

Why does this happen? How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: fonts aren't directly attached to the language

Comment: How to attach it?

Comment: not sure it's entirely possible, but this could be a good read on the topic: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: But there's nothing about fonts. So I cannot apply I font to another language?

Answer (score 1):

use this lib to add font programatically  to your app

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not because of me. It turned out, that this font simply doesn't support Russian letters.For example, when I added German to my project, the font worked perfectly.